# Using rxjs to change member name

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm learning rxjs.  I am getting JSON data back from an API.

**The data looks like:**

```
[
  {
   "entryDate":"01/01/2019",
   "categoryName":"Meeting"
   },
   {
   "entryDate":"01/02/2019",
   "categoryName":"Meeting"
   }
]
```

**I need to change the JSON in typescript to look like this:**

```
[
   {
    "date":"01/01/2019",
    "title":"Meeting"
    },
    {
    "date":"01/02/2019",
    "title":"Meeting"
   }
]
```

I have been researching map and mapTo.  I think mapTo might be my answer, but I don't want to change the value, only the member name.

In the end, I need to map (or something) entryDate --> date and categoryName --> title.  I think I have to chain that in the subscribe.

**My typescript that gets the data from the API is:**

```
calendarEntries: ICalendarEntry[] = [];

this._dashboardService.getCalendar().subscribe(
  calendarEntries => {
    this.calendarEntries = calendarEntries;
  }
);
```

Comment: `mapTo` is used more when you want to emit the same value for every event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can write a function that solves the converting for you:**

```
// This is a converter function for your {entryDate, categoryName} to {date, title}
function converter(input) {
  return {date: input.entryDate, title: input.categoryName}
}
```

**Then use it in your pipe:**

```
// This is your converted Observable Stream with the updated Objects: {date, title}[]
const convertedSource$ = source$.pipe(
  map(items => items.map(converter))
)
```

**Working example:**

[RxJS-array-convert-pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-array-convert-pipe)

*Open the console to see the Output*

Answer (score 3):

**You can try:**

```
arr = [
  {
    "entryDate": "01/01/2019",
    "categoryName": "Meeting"
  },
  {
    "entryDate": "01/02/2019",
    "categoryName": "Meeting"
  }
]

ngOnInit() {
  let source2$ = Observable.from(this.arr)
  .map(({ entryDate, categoryName }) => new ICalendarEntry(entryDate, categoryName))
  .subscribe(
    data => { console.log('each item:' ,data);
  })
}  

class ICalendarEntry {
  "date": string;
  "title": string;

  constructor(date: string, title:string) {
    this.date = date;
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

or if you are getting the whole array from response not item by item you should try:

```
let sub = new ReplaySubject(2);
sub.next(this.arr);
sub.pipe(map((items: any[]) => items.map((item) => new ICalendarEntry(item.entryDate, item.categoryName))))
  .subscribe(value => {
    console.log('whole array:' , value);
  });

class ICalendarEntry {
  "date": string;
  "title": string

  constructor(date: string, title: string) {
    this.date = date;
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-rxjs-observable-operator-map-an9gfg)

Comment: prefixing interfaces with I is discouraged https://v7.angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

Comment: This solution worked as well, but I would've had to change my interfaces to classes.  Thank you!